# Is is possible to use a private Pod in a public Pod?

Tags: cocoapods

I'm creating a public Pod which is using a private Pod. Here, if I try to push the public pod, it's showing some error messages like "Can't find the specification".

Is it possible to use the private Pod inside the public Pod?

Comment: What is the point of publishing a pod if other people can't use it because they can't get the dependencies?

Comment: @Paulw11If its a private pod mean we could use inside our teams.

Comment: Either the pod and its dependencies are private or thempod and its dependencies are public

Comment: @Paulw11 Can you be more clear

Answer (score 1):

**No.**

If one of your pods is private, that means it's only accessible to you. Since Pods are not like embedded libraries, the source code needs to be accessible to the host as well.

In essence, the dependencies should have a higher or an equal access level as the host project.